# Scala Slick 3 Playframework

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

Kind of stuck trying to port an old php application to scala, what I want:
I have nodes (model) that look like this:

```
id | parent_id
```

now for a given node

```
case class Node(id: Option[Long], parentID: Option[Long])

private def filterQuery(id: Long): Query[Nodes, Node, Seq] = nodes.filter(_.id === id)

override def find(id: Long): Future[Option[Node]] =
{
    try db.run(filterQuery(id).result.headOption)
    finally db.close
}
```

I want to get all the parents recursively, like:

```
private def getAllParents(node: Node): List[Node] = node.parentID match
{
  case l:Long => List(node) + getAllParents(find(l))
  case None => List(node)
}
```

of course this doesn't work.

1. the syntax is not right. I need to add the node to the list AND call it for it's parent
2. the recursive call wouldn't work because it expects Node but gets Future[Option[Node]], not sure how to resolve this either :(

I remember doing Haskell a few years back and my functional style is a (huge) bit rusty.

edit: I see that I would probably need to have the list as parameter as well... argh, I'm so stuck -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to include the list as a parameter, but you will need to use a nested function to do that.

The main issue here is that `find` returns a `Future[Option[Node]]`, so that means you need to work entirely "inside" futures.  A `Future` is a monad, which basically means two things:

1. You can never directly access value inside the `Future`
2. You interact with the contained value by passing functions to it through `map` and `flatMap`, which give you a new `Future` in return.

I would suggest you read some articles about how future-based programming works, [here's](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html) a decent one I found, but as a simplified example, suppose I have :

```
val x: Future[Int] = Future { 5 }
```

If I want to add 1 to the contained value, I cannot access it directly, but rather I can call `map`:

```
val y: Future[Int] = x.map{i => i + 1}
```

Likewise, if I have some function like :

```
def addOne(i: Int): Future[Int] = //...
```

I can use it with my future like :

```
val y: Future[Int] = x.flatMap{i => addOne(i)}
```

Getting back to your situation, this means that `getAllParents` must return a `Future[List[Node]]` and we will do the recursion using `flatMap`, where you create a new future every time you call find and chain them together as you traverse through them.

```
private def getAllParents(node: Node): Future[List[Node]] = {
  def loop(node: Node, build: List[Node]): Future[List[Node]] = {
    node.parentId match {
      case None => Future.successful(node :: build)
      case Some(parentId) => find(parentId).flatMap{parentOption => parentOption match {
        case Some(parentNode) => loop(parentNode, node :: build)
        case None => throw new Exception(s"couldn't find parent for $node")
      }}
    }
  }
  loop(node, Nil)
}
```

So you can see that `loop` is sort of a recursive function, but the recursion is done inside a `Future`.  If the node has no parent, then we basically stick the end result directly in a new `Future` and call it a day.  If the node does have a parent, we then call `find`, which gives us a `Future[Option[Node]]`.

Now to do the recursion, we call `flatMap` on this returned `Future`, and we have to give it a function of type `Option[Node] => Future[List[Node]]`.  Now we have a function that has access to both `node` and its parent, and we can add `node` to the list and call `loop` again on its parent.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I'm not yet comfortable with Futures at all. I do need the "recursively found parents" to build up a tree in another table (it's a closure table implementation) and Futures are "just" a contract that sometime there will be something. (If I understood this correctly) So it's kind of "No, I want that ASAP!" :X

Comment: One more question: I already have a TableQuery:  private val nodes = TableQuery[Nodes] and private def all(): Query[Nodes, Node, Seq] = nodes would using them instead of find not greatly improve the performance (just one fetch instead of many). How could I filter through these instead?